# Упрощенная функция PHP

Tags: php, функции

Уважаемые знатоки и просто друзья. Вопрос довольно простой. Прошу сильно не ругать  Создаю простейшую функцию

```
function weekday () {
$weekday = date('w') ;
                        if ($weekday ==0) { 
                        echo "<ul class='timer-weekdays mb-10'>
                                <li><a href='#' class='label label-default'>Пн</a></li>
                                <li><a href='#' class='label label-default'>Вт</a></li>
                                <li><a href='#' class='label label-default'>Ср</a></li>
                                <li><a href='#' class='label label-default'>Чт</a></li>
                                <li><a href='#' class='label label-default'>Пт</a></li>
                                <li><a href='#' class='label label-default'>Суб</a></li>
                                <li  class='active'><a href='#' class='label label-danger'>Вос</a></li>
                        </ul>" ; }
if ($weekday ==1) { 
                        echo "<ul class='timer-weekdays mb-10'>
                                <li class='active'><a href='#' class='label label-danger'>Пн</a></li>
                                <li><a href='#' class='label label-default'>Вт</a></li>
                                <li><a href='#' class='label label-default'>Ср</a></li>
                                <li><a href='#' class='label label-default'>Чт</a></li>
                                <li><a href='#' class='label label-default'>Пт</a></li>
                                <li><a href='#' class='label label-default'>Суб</a></li>
                                <li><a href='#' class='label label-default'>Вос</a></li>
                        </ul>" ; }}
```

Как вы уже наверное заметили что функция берет числовое значение дня недели и соответственно отмечает его в блоке кода. В голову пришло только такая идеяю Но 7 раз писать одно и тоже как бы тоже не дело. Как можно упростить данную функцию. У кого какие идеи ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Привет друг! Логика простая, мы просто добавляем массивы и циклы в вашей функции и все будет хорошо.

```
function weekday () {
    $weekday = date('w');
    $dateArr = array('', 'Пн', 'Вт','Ср','Чт','Пт','Сб','Вс');

    echo '<ul class="timer-weekdays mb-10">';
    for($i=1; $i<8; $i++){
        if($i == $weekday){
            echo '<li class="active"><a href="#" class="label label-danger">';
        }else{
            echo '<li><a href="#" class="label label-default">';
        }

        echo $dateArr[$i].'</a></li>';
     }
     echo '</ul>';
}
```

Comment: `label-danger` только у активного выводится

Comment: @teran, исправил

Comment: Всё просто и ясно ) Спасибо !

Comment: @Node_pro вместо дублирования разметки (там где проверка на текущий день), можно было бы просто заполнять переменную `$class` для li, а потом подставлять ее, сократив таким образом условие с 5 строк до 2))

Comment: @DaemonHK, можно было и через тернарный оператор "?" сделать, но я сделал как можно проще, так как автор поста - скорее всего не так давно занимается разработкой и хотелось, чтобы он понял